# Querying MSSQL 2012 from VBSCRIPT using ADODB

Tags: sql-server, vbscript

I am having a hard time filling a recordset with data from an MSSQL 2012 server using ADODB.
Below is the code that is not working, along with the error I am receiving.

I have used this exact same setup to query data from an MSSQL 2008r2 server without issue.

I know that my SELECT statement is accurate and correct.  If I take my select statement and paste it into a new query window in sql server management studio, it returns data.

```
Dim mConnection

Set mConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

mConnection.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=rwdwstage","SA","PASSWORDREDACTED"

Set Tech_RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

SQLstr = "SELECT QDSTCD, QDAREA, QDBANK FROM [RWDATA].[dbo].[BRDETAIL] where QDSDT = '20151215' and QDSTCD = 'WI'"

Tech_RS.open SQLstr, mConnection

Do while not Tech_RS.EOF
    wscript.echo Tech_RS.Fields("QDSTCD") & " - " & Tech_RS.Fields("QDAREA") & " - " & Tech_RS.Fields("QDBANK")
    Tech_RS.MoveNext
Loop
```

Error Returned

> ```
> cscript ..\HIST_Transfer\test2.vbs
> Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> ..\HIST_Transfer\test2.vbs(11, 1) Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
> ```

Any help that could be provided would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: `mConnection.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=rwdwstage;Initial Catalog=RWDATA","SA","PASSWORDREDACTED"` and:  `SQLstr = "SELECT QDSTCD, QDAREA, QDBANK FROM [dbo].[BRDETAIL] where QDSDT = '20151215' and QDSTCD = 'WI'"`

Comment: That worked!  Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add `Initial Catalog` to connection string:

```
mConnection.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=rwdwstage;Initial Catalog=RWDATA","SA","PASSWORDREDACTED"
```

and change query to:

```
SQLstr = "SELECT QDSTCD, QDAREA, QDBANK FROM [dbo].[BRDETAIL] where QDSDT = '20151215' and QDSTCD = 'WI'"
```

---

I guess that it worked before because the default database, for login you use for connecting, was `RWDATA` and with newer version it points to another DB (you can try to change default DB for that login and check if it works, be aware that changing it may broke other application that relies on default DB)